# How do I move project folders in PyCharm Project View?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm to do a few Django projects and I have them all open in the Project View to the left. I'd like to move the project I'm currently working on to the bottom of the list to avoid confusion. PyCharm does not let me do this by default. Are there some settings that need tweaking before I can do this? Take a look at this screenshot. What I want to do is to be able to is to click and drag *'Django_pro'* to the bottom of the list and then expand the tree. Can this be achieved?

[image: Project View window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK the display order in the file navigator panel (any of them - `Project`, `Project Files`, etc.) is not arbitrarily user-selectable.

To avoid the confusion it would probably be a better idea to actually split your django projects into **separate** PyCharm projects - what you have right now is just a **single** PyCharm project which contains files spread across multiple directories. The split will also save you trouble down the road by preventing potential conflicts between your projects.

With separate PyCharm projects there is no room for such confusion as each project is open in its own window (even when chosing to re-use the Pycharm window the existing project is closed when a new one opens). From [Opening, Reopening and Closing Projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/opening-reopening-and-closing-projects.html) doc section:

> PyCharm allows opening several projects simultaneously in different
>   windows. By default, each time you open a project while another one is
>   opened, PyCharm prompts you to choose whether to open the project in
>   the same window or in a new window. If necessary, you can change this
>   behavior using controls on the System Settings page.
>
> In the **Project Opening** section of this page, you can choose one of
>   the following options:
>
> - **Open project in a new window** to open a new PyCharm window each time a new project is opened.
> - **Open project in the same window** to stay in the same PyCharm window.
> - **Confirm window to open project in** to keep the default behavior and display a dialog box to choose how to open each new project.

You might want to scan through the entire [Creating and Managing Projects](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-and-managing-projects.html) chapter and/or the [Creating and managing Django project](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Creating+and+managing+Django+project#CreatingandmanagingDjangoproject-CreatingaDjangoproject) tutorial.